# There were undefined references. and Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) document(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

I am new to texstudio. I am writing an article on texstudio. I used the Zotero application for creating a .bib file (my bib in my case). Here is the code below that I have written

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{article}
\date{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}    
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \title{A review on methods and pestimation}
    \maketitle
\hline
    \begin{abstract}
    Purpose of review: \\
        Summary: \\
        Conclusion:
    \end{abstract}
\hline
    \newpage    
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{Optical remote sensing}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c }
            \hline
            Study area & Dataset(Resolution)  & Parameters  & Allometric  model& Regression tool (method)&  Reference \\            
            \hline
            4  & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 & \cite{muukkonen_biomass_2007} \\
            7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &8 & \cite{leboeuf_shadow_2007} \\
            4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 & \cite{giannetti_new_2018} \\
            7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &8 & \cite{thenkabail_biomass_2004}\\
            4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 &\cite{meng_linear_2007} \\
            4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 &\cite{foody_predictive_2003} \\
            7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &8 &\cite{rahman_satellite_2008} \\
            4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 &\cite{du_satellite-based_2012} \\
            7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &8 & \cite{wicaksono_mangrove_2016} \\
            4 & 5 & 6 & 7 &8 & \cite{eckert_improved_2012}                      
                \end{tabular}
            \end{adjustbox}         
           \hline
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\newpage
References
\bibstyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{my bib}
\end{document}
```

I have encountered an error (well described in the image attached). please help me. Any small help is appreciated [image: screen shot of the error]

Comment: At first handle the errors. Start with the first one.

Comment: There are (at least) three issues you need to fix. First, you can't have `\hline` directives outside `tabular` and `array` environments. Did you maybe mean to write `\hrule` rather than `\hline` in two cases? Second, `\bibstyle{unsrt}` cannot possibly be correct. Did you mean to write `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`? Third, since your code contains (or should contain) a `\bibliographystyle` directive, you should under no circumstance be loading the `biblatex` package. Do please take the time to learn how to use BibTeX to create bibliographies and citation call-outs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX!

Concerning the bibliography, you used the syntax of standard packages with `bibtex`, not `biblatex` syntax:

- `\bibstyle{unsrt}` in the body of the document should be replaced with `\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}` in the preamble.
- Similarly, `\bibliography{my bib}` should be replaced with `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}` in the preamble. Note  the extension of the file is required, and there should be no space in its name.
- To obtain the bibliography in the .pdf, just add `\printbibliography` in the document body at the place you want it.

Comment: Sir, I tried your logic but it did not work. These warnings are showing : 1) 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing, 2) There were undefined references, and 3) Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) document(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards. And sir can you please tell me what is meant by preamble and where to exactly add them in the latex code (code attached with the question)? And also sir please advise me on how to run bibliography (procedure) in texstudio. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 3) The preamble is the part from `\documentclass` to `begin{document}`. Afterwards, the documentbody (what will be printed) begins. 1) You should add `\usepackage[some options]{csquotes}` to the preamble. The options defines which kind of quotes you want (this depends on the language in use), you'll find details in the package documentation. 2) Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex ->biber -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: Thank you, sir. It helped me.